# Migrating OS/contents of one SSD to another SSD

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, data-migration

I have a 120GB SSD which I have loaded my OS (windows 10) on. I then used a 1TB HDD as a storage Drive. I wanted to keep some programs/files on my SSD while using the 1TB HDD as my main storage. I bought a new 500GB SSD and I want to merge all contents (including OS) of my 120GB SSD to my 500GB SSD. Here is a snippet of my disk management:

[image: enter link description here]

I tried using AOMEI OS Migration tool, but it did not work. (EaseUS free trial did not allow OS Migration). I then tried to use MiniTool Professional Trial version and use its OS Migration Tool. It failed because the bootable volume and the system volume are not on the same disk. My bootable disk is the 120GB SSD, with the 1TB HDD as the system volume. (Not sure how to change this.)

In addition, After I get this migrated over, would it be possible to use the 120GB SSD as a cache to my 1TB HDD?

Answer (score -1):

One software I love using, and that I've had good success with is the EaseUS partition manager. To be clear, I've never done a copy using the current system disk - I've always used it to copy a DIFFERENT disk to the currently active OS (such as transferring other OSes onto SSDs, etc), so I'm not entirely sure how different the process is for copying an active disk.

UPDATE: I just read your thing about already using EaseUS, but don't bother using their "OS Migration" tool. Literally just copy the partitions. It's free, and pretty easy. I just dunno about how it function on active disks (as I described above)

If you feel like more of a SuperUser, you can always use the Linux Recovery environment included in HirensBootCD - from here, you can use GParted to copy the partition from one drive to the other. Be warned, that this method is much more involved, and if you don't know what you're doing you can brick your drives. Serious. You have been warned.